# Принцип работы icq и других клиентов.

Tags: сеть, icq, сервер

Как в icq или подобном клиенте проходит обмен сообщениями?
Кажется он там идет через сервер. Предположим, что это так (если не так, то как?)

Когда пользователь 1 отправляет сообщения пользователю 2, то сообщения сохраняется на сервере. И дальше пользователь 2 отправляет запрос на сервер на получения сообщений и получает ответ. Тогда выходит, что пользователь 2 должен постоянно отправлять запросы на сервер, чтобы узнать есть ли ему сообщения ( тоже самое проделывает пользователь 1 ).

ЭТО ТАК? Если не так, то как? можно подробнее.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто о сложном - [как работает jabber](http://sgolovan.nes.ru/jabber/userguide/ar01s03.html)

Comment: стало понятней, но как отправляется запрос в пункте 2? (Через UDP или TCP).
И как сервер посылает сообщения Ромео в пункте 5? (UDP или TCP)

Comment: Все просто - сокеты. Почитать можно тут - http://programmersforum.ru/showthread.php?t=68668 (обрати внимание на картинку с синими квадратами, там понятно расписано)